# ctypes uint64 conversion error

Tags: python, ctypes, uint64, nidaqmx

I got the following problem :

I load via c types the nicaiu.dll to control a `NI-USB6218` Data Acquisition Pad and i have to call several function to initialise it `(DAQmxCreateTask(), DAQmxCreateAIVoltageChan() and  DAQmxCfgSampClkTiming()` ).

The first two calls work but `DAQmxCfgSampClkTiming()` raises this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/*********/Voltage.py", line 68, in <module>
values)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 6: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert
parameter 6
```

Parameter 6 should be uint64 see [Doc](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370471Y-01/daqmxcfunc/daqmxcfgsampclktiming/)
This is my function call:

```
DAQmx_Val_Rising = 10280 #see NIDAQmx.h
DAQmx_Val_FiniteSamps = 10178 # see NIDAQmx.h
values = uint64(40000) #numpy function
dll.DAQmxCfgSampClkTiming(taskHandle, "OnboardClock", c_float(4000.0), DAQmx_Val_Rising, DAQmx_Val_FiniteSamps,
                                    values)
```

I also tried  `values = c_uint64(40000)` but it did not work.

**Edit1:**
The dll is located in System32 folder (Win7)

```
dll = cdll.nicaiu
```

E.g this function call works (returnvalue = 0)

```
DAQmx_Val_Diff = 10106
DAQmx_Val_RSE = 10083
DAQmx_Val_Volts = 10348
returnvalue = dll.DAQmxCreateAIVoltageChan(taskHandle, "Dev1/ai1", taskName, DAQmx_Val_RSE,
                                           c_float(-1.0),c_float(1.0), DAQmx_Val_Volts, None)
```

**Edit2:**

Added argtypes line

```
dll.DAQmxCfgSampClkTiming.argtypes = [c_int, c_char_p, c_float, c_int32, c_int32, c_uint64]
returnvalue = dll.DAQmxCfgSampClkTiming(taskHandle, None, c_float(4000.0), DAQmx_Val_Rising,
                                        DAQmx_Val_FiniteSamps,values)
```

Still get Error Code -200077 
Definition of this code is :

```
nierror code = -200077
Requested value is not a supported value for this property. The property value may be invalid
because it conflicts with another property.
```

Comment: Can you post more code? How are you opening the DLL? It looks like you aren't using `argtypes`.

Comment: Added more code to my question

Comment: How is TaskHandle defined?

Comment: taskHandle = c_int(0)  # daqmx taskhandle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test it as I don't have that instrument, but I would start with something like:

```
samp_clk_timing = dll.DAQmxCfgSampClkTiming
samp_clk_timing.restype = c_int32
samp_clk_timing.argtypes = (TaskHandle,
                            c_char_p,          
                            c_double,         
                            c_int32,
                            c_int32,           
                            c_uint64)

return_val = samp_clk_timing(taskHandle,
                             "OnboardClock",
                             c_double(4000),
                             c_int32(10106),
                             c_int32(10178),
                             c_uint64(40000))
```

Comment: now it works :D
i had to change the first argtype to c_int and at the function call the 4th and 5th to the right values for Rising Edge and Finite Samples 
Thx a lot :D

Comment: Strictly speaking TaskHandle should probably be a structure, but if it's only and int then nevermind :)

Comment: yeah initially it is defined as a void * 
but by calling DAQmxCreateTask it gets a memory address (i saw somewhere long long )